# DOMXPATH Evaluate string with variable nested position

Tags: php, domxpath

I've been using DOMXPATH and I love it, but I need it to be a little more intuitive.
Some clients add some extra HTML in their code, which screws up our project.

Example 1:

```
<div id="Fooen">
    <span class="FooTitle">Overdracht</span>
    <span class="Foo  koopprijs">
            <span class="FooName">Vraagprijs</span> 
            <span class="FooValue">€ 299.000,-</span>
    </span>
    <span class="Foo  aanvaarding">
            <span class="FooName">Aanvaarding</span> 
            <span class="FooValue">In overleg</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

We can get the SPAN name and values fine with this:

```
$filtered           = $domxpath->query("//div[@class='Fooen']/span");
foreach ($filtered as $myItem) {
    $temp_name = $domxpath->evaluate("string(descendant::span[@class='FooName'])", $myItem);            
    $name      = strtolower(preg_replace('/\s*/', '', $temp_name));
    $value     = $domxpath->evaluate("string(descendant::span[@class='FooValue'])", $myItem);           
}
```

But, sometimes the client added code, so the nodes are now deeper. I cannot seem to find an answer to this without mapping it all the way down.

Example 2:

```
<div id="Fooen">
    <div>
        <div class="blok-sizer"></div>
        <div id="" class="block">
            <div class="top">
                <div class="center column"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="center column">
                    <span class="FooTitle">Overdracht</span>
                    <span class="Foo first transactiestatus">
                        <span class="FooName">Status</span>
                        <span class="FooValue">Beschikbaar</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="Foo  koopprijs">
                        <span class="FooName">Vraagprijs</span> 
                        <span class="FooValue">€ 975.000,-</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But now, this won't work:

```
$filtered           = $domxpath->query("//div[@class='Fooen']/span");
foreach ($filtered as $myItem) {
    $temp_name = $domxpath->evaluate("string(descendant::span[@class='FooName'])", $myItem);            
    $name      = strtolower(preg_replace('/\s*/', '', $temp_name));
    $value     = $domxpath->evaluate("string(descendant::span[@class='FooValue'])", $myItem);           
}
```

I have tried variations like these:

```
$domxpath->evaluate("string(descendant::*[@class='FooName'])", $myItem);            
$domxpath->evaluate("string(//*[@class='FooName'])", $myItem);            
$domxpath->evaluate("string(*[@class='FooName'])", $myItem); 
$domxpath->evaluate("string(.//span[@class='FooName'])", $myItem);
```

Is there a way to get the outcome of a string, even if it is not at the same place each time, thus more flexible?

Edit, here is a ready to copy/paste sample I am currently working with. First is the working one, second is the one I'd like to get working from root to end and not fixed but flexible. If I knew how to fiddle, I would, sorry.

```
<?php

function getDom($url = "")
{
    $str            = $url;
    $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom            = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $dom->loadHTML($str);
    libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
    return $dom;
}

$domcode = '<div class="Fooen">
    <span class="FooTitle">Overdracht</span>
    <span class="Foo  koopprijs">
            <span class="FooName">Vraagprijs</span> 
            <span class="FooValue">€ 299.000,-</span>
    </span>
    <span class="Foo  aanvaarding">
            <span class="FooName">Aanvaarding</span> 
            <span class="FooValue">In overleg</span>
    </span>
</div>';

$dom                  = getDom($domcode);
$html                 = '';
$domxpath             = new \DOMXPath($dom);
$newDom               = new \DOMDocument;
$newDom->formatOutput = true;


$filtered = $domxpath->query("//div[@class='Fooen']/span");
foreach ($filtered as $myItem) {
    $temp_name = $domxpath->evaluate("string(descendant::span[@class='FooName'])", $myItem);
    echo strtolower(preg_replace('/\s*/', '', $temp_name));
    echo " = ";
    echo $domxpath->evaluate("string(descendant::span[@class='FooValue'])", $myItem);
    echo "<br>";
}


echo "<br>";

$domcode = '
<div class="Fooen">
    <div>
        <div class="blok-sizer"></div>
        <div id="" class="block">
            <div class="top">
                <div class="center column"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="center column">
                    <span class="FooTitle">Overdracht</span>
                    <span class="Foo first transactiestatus">
                        <span class="FooName">Status</span>
                        <span class="FooValue">Beschikbaar</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="Foo  koopprijs">
                        <span class="FooName">Vraagprijs</span> 
                        <span class="FooValue">€ 975.000,-</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';


$dom                  = getDom($domcode);
$html                 = '';
$domxpath             = new \DOMXPath($dom);
$newDom               = new \DOMDocument;
$newDom->formatOutput = true;

$filtered = $domxpath->query("//div[@class='center column']/span");

foreach ($filtered as $myItem) {
    $temp_name = $domxpath->evaluate("string(descendant::span[@class='FooName'])", $myItem);
    echo "<br>";
    echo strtolower(preg_replace('/\s*/', '', $temp_name));
    echo " = ";
    echo $domxpath->evaluate("string(descendant::span[@class='FooValue'])", $myItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had been beating the wrong line of code all day. Apparently I needed to broaden the Filtered Search. If there's room for non-greedy code I'm all ears. Otherwise, I hope it helps somebody else.

```
$filtered = $domxpath->query("//div[@class='Fooen']/descendant::span");
```